# Как прервать чтение по таймеру?

Tags: windows, c, mingw, unix, linux

Программа на C, ОС — Windows XP, компилятор — MinGW GCC 3.4.5. Нужен аналог `alarm()` — `SIGALRM`. Этого в MinGW нет. Вместо `alarm()` использовал `timeSetEvent()` из `libwinmm.a`. Callback отрабатывает, но `read()` (на самом деле `gets()` с консоли) не прерывается (по `SIGINT` (<kbd>^C</kbd>) — прерывается). Вызов `raise` (`SIGILL`) из Callback не помогает. Похоже, Callback и основная программа — это разные потоки, а `raise` генерит сигнал в текущем потоке, то есть в потоке Callback.

Как послать сигнал (в реализации MinGW) в другой поток? Заодно, как определить текущий thread (к сожалению, в Windows я не силен)? Каким еще образом можно прервать ожидание ввода? Желательно получить :

```
read() == -1; errno == EINTR.
```

Собственно, задача состоит в эмуляции `alarm()`, то есть вызове подпрограммы через заданное время. Крайне полезный побочный эффект — прерывание системного вызова (особенно ожидающего события), во время работы которого (системного вызова) сработал таймер. Решение для конкретного случая с использованием `setjmp()` очевидно, хотелось бы обойтись без него (или максимально спрятать его на уровне вызова `alarm()`).

**Уточнение.**

@duff, @тимур, благодарю за внимание.

Хочу сделать `alarm()` для MinGW (Windows) с поведением аналогично SYSV Unix (то есть блокируемый системный вызов (например `read()` при срабатывании таймера прерывается).

Вообще говоря, при вызове `alarm()` неизвестно, будет ли блокировка на сокете, на консоли или на паузе (`Sleep()`). Желательно прерывать ЛЮБОЕ ожидание. К сожалению, я практически не владею WinAPI, поэтому не знаю, как из вызванной по срабатыванию таймера CallBack функции:

1. определить, находится ли поток (thread) с `main()` в состоянии ожидания. (ждет какого-либо семафора в ядре?) (предполагаем однопоточную с точки зрения программиста, вызывающего `alarm()`, схему).
2. прервать ожидание с возвратом из системного вызова (наверное правильно говорить о функции WinAPI ?) с осмысленным результатом.

Если можно поподробнее о том, где почитать о `kbhit`, `ReadFile`, `CancelIO`.

Надеюсь правильно понял (особенно ХэшКод).

Благодарю всех за советы по WinAPI, буду изучать и пробовать.

Искренне Ваш, avp

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, Вам нужно прервать именно чтение с консоли? Если это так, то может есть смысл использовать связку _kbhit/_getch, чтобы не блокировать консоль?

Comment: @avp Здесь правильно редактировать исходный вопрос или добавлять комментарий, вместо создания уточняющего ответа.

Comment: По функциям вся информация - в MSDN.

Comment: Ну, теперь, правка (по совету ХэшКод), надеюсь получится

Comment: Да, теперь OK.

Comment: @avp Все правильно. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы не блокировать ввод, можно попробовать:

- для POSIX - `kbhit` + `select`;
- для WinAPI - `ReadFile` + `CancelIO`.

Еще раз перечитал вопрос. Если просто нужно прервать чтение по таймеру, то `select` — лучший вариант.

Чтобы реализовать `alarm()` для MinGW, придется работать с Windows API (я другого способа не вижу). Вам потребуются

- `CreateThread`
- `WaitForSingleObject`
- `SetWaitableTimer`

Об этих и других функциях, которые понадобятся, а также примерах их использования лучше всего читать прямо в MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

На Windows API вызов подпрограммы через определенный промежуток времени достигается с помощью функции
SetTimer, которая при обращении получает адрес отложенной функции (callback), а уведомление о событии в другой поток передается функцией SetEvent.